# Rspec spec failing on update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following request spec

```
it "updates an open time" do
  # Create an OpenTime
  open_time = OpenTime.create(:start_time => (Time.now + 2.hours), :end_time => (Time.now + 10.hours))
  # Build an open_time update param
  params = {:open_time => {:start_time => (Time.now + 5.hours)}}
  # Send param to open_times#update
  put open_time_path(open_time.id) , params
  # Check to see if OpenTime was updated
  open_time.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({:start_time => (Time.now + 5.hours)})
end
```

Here is my open_times controller

```
def update
  @open_time = OpenTime.find(params[:id])
  if @open_time.update_attributes(params[:open_time])
    flash[:success] = "Time updated."
    redirect_to @open_time
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Test is failing with expected : 1 received: 0

Comment: try to run **open_time.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({:start_time => (Time.now + 5.hours)})** before **put open_time_path(open_time.id) , params**

Comment: still fails with same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not that object that will receive `update_attributes`, but a new object returned by `OpenTime.find`, therefore, you should make sure that find returns your object:

```
OpenTime.stub(:find).and_return(open_time)
open_time.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({:start_time => (Time.now + 5.hours)})
```

and then:

```
put open_time_path(open_time.id) , params
```

additionaly, I would add `target_time = Time.now + 5.hours` at the beginning of the test, and then use that time in params and matcher.

Comment: Thanks! Just had to change to `OpenTime.stub(:find).and_return(open_time)
    open_time.should_receive(:update_attributes!).with({"start_time" => (Time.now + 5.hours).to_s })` and it passed!

Answer (score 1):

As [kr1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305475/kr1) noticed you have to stub OpenTime.find method to return your instance of OpenTime when it gets called from the controller. Change your test code to:

```
it "updates an open time" do
  target_time = (Time.now + 5.hours)
  # Create an OpenTime
  open_time = OpenTime.create(:start_time => (Time.now + 2.hours), :end_time => (Time.now + 10.hours))

  # Build an open_time update param
  params = {:open_time => {:start_time => target_time}}

  # Stub OpenTime to return your instance
  OpenTime.stub(:find).and_return(open_time)

  # Set expectation on open_time to receive :update_attributes
  open_time.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({:start_time => target_time})

  # Send param to open_times#update
  put open_time_path(open_time.id) , params
end
```

What is happening here is that you build your instance of OpenTime(open_time) and by stubbing OpenTime class you are saying "if someone call find on OpenTime class don't run find but simply return open_time(instance you just created)". Then you set up expectation on your instance to receive :update_attributes. When you call **put open_time_path(open_time.id) , params** your controller create action will process request and OpenTime.find(...) will return your instance(open_time) and call :update_attribute on it.

Hope it make a sense.